# Json Authentication to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I am trying to setup json based authentication on my current rails app. The app's authentication is currently handled by devise.

I have read couple of questions on stackoverflow, but I do not seem to get it working.

**routes.rb:**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :sessions => 'users/sessions' }
```

**SessionsController:**

```
class Users:: SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)
    return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true, :redirect => stored_location_for(scope) || after_sign_in_path_for(resource)}
  end

  def failure
    return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
end
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong. The call I am making is:

**JSON:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
data: {user: {password: mypass, email: some_email@gmail.com}}
```

**The Error:**

```
MultiJson::DecodeError (756: unexpected token at '{user: {password: mypass, email:    some_email@gmail.com}}'):
2012-06-30T18:10:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.5/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste that JSON into http://jsonlint.com, you get the same error.. Instead, you should wrap your values in quotes:

```
{
    "user": {
        "password": "mypass",
        "email": "some_email@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: slightly off-topic - when a login fails, the return value is not the json failure - instead it returns the html root page. Any idea why?

Comment: @Newton I wrote about similar here: http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/